# How to Apply a function on this DataFrame to change the Date to required format and avoid '0' and '-'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a Data Frame like this

```
A     Date
'a'   "0"
"b"   "2019-08-13T16:16:59.000Z"
"c"   -
"d"  "'2019-01-10T07:31:56"
"e"   "2019-05-03T08:12:09.000Z"
"f"   "0"
"g"   -
```

Which i want to export to an excel after changing them to required format, for that i am using the function below.

```
def time_str_to_date(utc: str):
    try:
        timecheck = datetime.datetime.strptime(utc,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    except ValueError:
        try:
            timecheck = datetime.datetime.strptime(utc,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
        except ValueError:
            try:
                timecheck = datetime.datetime.strptime(utc,'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
            except ValueError:
                try:
                    timecheck = datetime.datetime.strptime(utc,'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')
                except ValueError:
                    try:
                        timecheck = datetime.datetime.strptime(utc,'%Y-%m-%d')
                    except ValueError:
                        timecheck = datetime.datetime.strptime(utc,'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')

    return timecheck
```

My problem is i am using the below apply formats but it is giving me errors
**"time data 'NaT' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'"**

```
df['date']=df['date'].apply(lambda x:pd.NaT if x=='0' else x)

df['date'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x:time_str_to_date(str(x)) if x!='NaT' else x)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`to_datetime` with `errors='coerce'` will do:

```
 pd.to_datetime(df.Date, errors='coerce')
```

Output:

```
0                          NaT
1    2019-08-13 16:16:59+00:00
2                          NaT
3          2019-01-10 07:31:56
4    2019-05-03 08:12:09+00:00
5                          NaT
6                          NaT
Name: Date, dtype: object
```

Comment: Can i use it like df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df.Date,error='coerce')